# Memory allocation for immutable objects

Tags: python, tuples, immutability

For the string types, the memory location is the same for the same values. But, not for the tuples. Is there any reason for it? I was expecting the tuples and strings with the same data have the same memory location as both of them are immutable.

```
name1 = "praveen"
print(id(name1))

name2 = "praveen"
print(id(name2))

tuple1 = (1, 2, 3)
print(id(tuple1))

tuple2 = (1, 2, 3)
print(id(tuple2))
```

---

```
140568068832368
140568068832368
140568038719704
140568038719848
```

Comment: These are implementation details. Python makes no promises here. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I believe all empty tuples are the same, but that's the limit of tuple sharing in the standard Python implementation.

Comment: @user1767754: `(1)` isn't a tuple. `(1,)` is.

Comment: any more questions? if it helps, you can accept the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Such optimization is implementation-depended. A more complicated compiler/interceptor may implement more optimization methods. But, a compiler/interceptor must consider the trade-off of every optimization.

In my opinion:

> Is there any reason for it?

Detecting same strings is easy and fast, and can be more optimized by string hash, etc. Very fast. This method is usually called "string pooling".

Detecting same tuples is difficult and slow, especially when a tuple contains big objects. The cost of detecting same tuples may waste more time than the memory-saving benefit.

> I was expecting the tuples and strings with the same data have the same memory location as both of them are immutable.

A compiler/interceptor must detect same objects(string, tuple) first, then make later ones use the immutable existing one. If Python can not detect same tuples, he will not use the existing same one. As said before, Python may think that the cost is too high to detect complicated tuples, so he gives up.

For empty tuples, python does good because he knows it, it's easy :)

```
>>> a=()
>>> b=()
>>> id(a)
4553994312
>>> id(b)
4553994312
>>>
```

Comment: "Detecting same tuples is difficult and slow." This is a good point; tuples can contain any object, and there is no guarantee that those objects are even hashable and/or implement `__eq__()`.

Comment: Just a note that string pooling also depends on the context. It is usually only done for constants (that can be processed at compile time). e.g. `id("abc") != id("abc".encode().decode())"